# How do I use WHILE loop in CASE statement in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In 'CASE' statement in SQL we use a bool condition and get a TRUE or FALSE result. In this situation I have to use non-bool unlimited condition. But I can't...

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[sp_StudentList](@CreatedBy nvarchar(max))
as
begin
  declare @LikedBy nvarchar(max) = (Select LikedBy from LikeStatus)
  declare @TeacherRequestID int = (Select TeacherRequestID from LikeStatus where LikedBy=@CreatedBy)
  declare @UserName nvarchar(max) = @CreatedBy
  declare @i int = 1
  declare @NumberOfRows int = (select count(*) from TeacherRequest) 

  select SP.StuThana, SP.StuDist, TR.StudentName,TR.StudentCode, TR.Class, TR.Subject, TR.StuGroup,TR.StuRelation, TR.Institute,TR.Status, TR.LikeStatus,
         **CASE
         WHEN   
         WHILE(@i <= @NumberOfRows)
            BEGIN
                @TeacherRequestID = TR.ID THEN 'Liked' Else 'Like'      
                set @i = @i + 1       
            END      
        END as LikeFlag** 
    from StudentsProfile SP join TeacherRequest TR on SP.CreatedBy=TR.CreatedBy
--sp_StudentList 'teacher1@gmail.com'
end
```

Comment: What is your database name?

Comment: Which type of database are you using? MySQL? Postgres? Oracle? SQL Server? Also, what is the loop trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why to use a `while` loop when you have a perfectly good SQL database that can do `count(*)`?

Comment: When "TeacherRequestID"  variable has single value then code working without loop. But when "TeacherRequestID"  variable has multiple values then I need WHILE loop to iterate and compare all the values with "TR.ID "

I am using SQL server

Comment: TSQL has a [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) _expression_ and a [`while`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/while-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) _statement_. A `case` does not provide flow-of-control. And how do you manage to get multiple values into a single `int` (`@TeacherRequestID`)?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1):

The technical answer to your question as posed in your title is that you can't.

```
declare @i int = 5;
select case when (while @i > 0 begin set @i = @i - 1 end) then 1 else 0 end;
-- Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'while'
```

Is your intention to just determine whether a student listed in a row likes the associated teacher?  If so, then you're looking for whether an entry `exists` in another table, not how often it occurs.  And I would tie it to sp.createdBy, not @createdBy.

```
select     // ...,

           likeFlag = 
               case when exists (
                   select  0
                   from    likeStatus ls
                   where   ls.likedBy = sp.createdBy
                   and     ls.TeacherRequestId = tr.id
               ) then 'Liked' 
               else 'Like' 
               end

from      studentsProfile sp
join      teacherRequest tr on sp.createdBy = tr.createdBy
```

If for some reason you really only need 'Liked' based on @createdBy, then change `ls.likedBy = sp.createdBy` to `ls.likedBy = @createdBy`, but I don't see a strong use case for that.